# signed URL to post a file to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm completely stumped on creating a static web page to post a file to S3. I've used the sample code I found from this page (Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) but it's not working. I'm getting back "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

I have the bucket created and permissions are set to "objects can be public". I created a used in IAM and created a posting policy to the bucket. When I created the user, I copied the access key and secret key from IAM for the HTML, but it seems I'm not using the right keys?

Here is the HTML, with bucket name and keys changed as follows for the example:

Access Key: AccessKeyFromIAM

Secret key: SecretKeyGeneratedInIAM

Bucket name: mybucketname

HTML:

```
   <html>
   <head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
   </head>
   <body>

   <form action="http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}" /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html" />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256"/> 
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AccessKeyFromIAM/20191229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20191229T000000Z" />

    Tags for File: 
    <input type="input"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>' />
     <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="SecretKeyGeneratedInIAM" />
     File: 
     <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br/>
     <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
   </form>

   </html>
```

Comment: Do you simply put the secret key into `X-Amz-Signature` value? I don't this will work, you have to generate a signature instead. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Comment: Note that you can't do this with a "static" page.  The signature must be generated, server-side, when you build the form, as noted in the linked question.  The IAM user's secret key does not go in the form.